Splitting of chain complexes
I am reading homological algebra from Weibel’s book. I am stuck at the following checking.
Let $C^{\bullet}$ be a cochain complex with all terms injective and $H^{i}(C^{\bullet} )= 0$ for $i<r$. Then how to write $C^{\bullet}$ as $C_1^{\bullet} \oplus C_2^{\bullet}$ where $C_1^{\bullet}$ is exact such that $C_1^{\bullet}$ has elements in degrees $0\leq i \leq r$ and $C_2^{\bullet}$ has elements in degrees $i\geq r$?
I think i need to use splitting of chain complexes somehow but not sure how to do!
Thanks in advance.

Are you missing some conditions? As written at present you could just take $C^\bullet_1=0$ and $C^\bullet_2=C^\bullet$.

@JeremyRickard Sorry, I also need $C_1^{\bullet}$ has elements in degrees $0\leq i\leq r$ and $C_2^{\bullet}$ has elements in degrees $i\geq r$.

I have been working lately with Weibel’s book and I don’t recall this result. Could you provide the exact section in which it mentions it?

Please don’t just acknowledge in comments that you omitted something in the question. Edit the question so that people who read it later know what you mean!

$\require{AMScd}$
Even though you have not detailed anything about the boundedness of the chain complexes, I am going to assume that the complex is bounded from below considering your last comment.
In this case, I believe one can prove this statement by induction on $r \geq 0$ due to the boundedness condition. The base case $r=0$ is trivial. I can describe you what have I thought for the case in which $r=1$ and I guess that the inductive step is pretty much analogous. Suppose we have the following (co)chain complex
\begin{CD}
\cdots @> >> 0 @> >> C^0 @>{d^0} >> C^1 @>{d^1} >> \cdots
\end{CD}
Verifying that $H^i(C^{\bullet}) = 0, \hspace{1mm} i < r = 1$ and all of its components are injective objects. That is, we have that $H^0(C^{\bullet}) = 0$, which implies that the map $d^0$ is injective. Therefore, we may consider the following exact sequence:
\begin{CD}
0 @> >> C^0 @>{d^0} >> C^1 @>{\pi} >> C^1/d^0(C^0) @> >> 0
\end{CD}
Since $C^0$ is injective, the exact sequence splits and $C^1 \cong C^0 \oplus \mathrm{coker} \hspace{0.5mm} d^0$. In particular, we have shown that $\mathrm{coker} \hspace{0.5mm} d^0 $ is an injective object (why?). We then have the following commutative diagram which induces an isomorphism of chain complexes:
\begin{CD}
\cdots @>>> 0 @>>> C^0 @>{d^0} >> C^1 @>{d^1}>> C^2 @>>> \cdots \\
 @. @|  @| @V{}VV @| \\
\cdots @>>> 0 @>>> C^0 @>{(1 \hspace{2mm} 0)}>> C^0 \oplus \mathrm{coker} \hspace{0.5mm} d^0 @>{(0 \hspace{2mm} \overline{d^1})}>> C^2 @>>> \cdots   
\end{CD}
Which gives us the desired splitting $C^{\bullet} \cong C^{\bullet}_1 \oplus C^{\bullet}_2$ taking $C_1^{\bullet}$ as
\begin{CD}
 \cdots @>>> 0 @>>> C^0 @= C^0 @>>> 0 @>>> \cdots
\end{CD}
and $C^{\bullet}_2$ as the chain complex
\begin{CD}
\cdots @>>> 0 @>>> 0 @>>> \mathrm{coker} \hspace{0.5mm} d^0 @>{\overline{d^1}}>> C^2 @>>> \cdots
\end{CD}
